# Adobe Scout Event "enterframe"

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash-cs6, adobe-scout

Hey everyone quick question here. So when profiling my games performance in adobe scout I can see why my game is being really slow and frame rate drops from 30fps to 8fps. But I don't understand what this means exactly when I check what is causing it, it's the Actionscript. Specifically it states Event "enterframe" x5.

Does anyone know what the "x5" means? Is it stating that there are 5 active Enter Frame listeners currently active?